# Help in interpolating X

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a working formula below.

```
((9650 - 9450) / 9650) * 100 * 5 = 10.36
```

But assuming I dont know the value of 9650, so I substitute it with the value X.
What will be my new equation to get the same result of 10.36

```
((X - 9450) / X) * 100 * 5 = 10.36
```

I'm newbie in Math and I am having a hard time wrapping my head interpolating such equation so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how you would solve the equation for $X$?  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: What do you mean by "interpolating"? Does it mean you want to solve the equation? I'm asking because interpolation usually has a different meaning in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you interpolating?  You can just solve it for $X$.
$$((X - 9450) / X) * 100 * 5 = 10.36\\
\frac{X-9450}X=\frac {10.36}{500}\\
500X-500\cdot 9450=10.36X\\
(500-10.36)X=500\cdot 9450\\
X=\frac{500\cdot 9450}{500-10.36}$$
and $X=9650$ is approximately correct.  I get $9649\frac{946}{999}$

Comment: thanks very much @Ross Milikan